# "In detail" vs. "in details"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which form is correct: "in detail" or "in details"?

I want to use it while describing an algorithm. First I give a general description of an algorithm and then more detailed description.

Comment: You can also compare it with "in summary"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think

> In detail

Is correct. Assuming that the context looks like this.

> [After general description]
>
> In detail, the algorithm will....

But you could always say..

> Here, I describe the details of the algorithm.

Answer (score 12):

"you describe the algorithm in detail" or "you describe the details of the algorithm".